# openlayers module loading by requirejs

Tags: requirejs, openlayers-3

I am trying to make use of requirejs for openlayers 3 module loading.
I load ol3-layerswitcher library like this-

```
require(["./ol3-layerswitcher"],function(layerSwitcherObj)
            {
                console.log(layerSwitcherObj);
            });
```

// In ol3-layerswitcher file, i have to add ol.js dependency like,

```
 require(["./app/ol"],function(ol)
      {
         ol.control.LayerSwitcher = function(opt_options)'
           {
            // ......
           }
      });
```

The object ol is defined but the layerswitcherObj comes out to be undefined.Could anyone help me find the right way to do this?

Comment: `require(["./app/ol"],function(ol)` should be `define(["./app/ol"],function(ol)` since you want to define all that stuff as a module and use it (`require` it) later.    ...edit: if i understood your intent correctly..

Comment: @xmike thanks! But exactly what i want to do is , load ol3-layerswitcher as a module and then use its functions. But currently, i get undefined when i require it. But ol.js returns a proper object representing its namespace.